# Combine expression with function in ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, expression

I'd like to make a ggplot function that allows me to choose a dataset, the data on x and y axes, and the y-axis label as an expression, but I can't get the y-axis expression to be part of the function.

here's what I have so far:

```
x_vs_time <- function (data, xaxis, yaxis, yaxislabel) {
  
ggplot(data, aes(x = {{xaxis}}, 
                y= {{yaxis}}))+
  geom_point(size =3, alpha =0.5)+ 
  ylab (expression(yaxislabel)) 
  }

x_vs_time (alldata, daycount, nutrient_concentration, NO[3]~(mu*M))
```

When I run the function, the y-axis label appears as the variable name in the function,"yaxislabel", and I haven't been able fix it.
I can include it as a normal label, but I have multiple expressions that I'd like to include in several plots, like :

- ylab (expression (Si:NO3~drawdown))
- ylab (expression (NO[3]~(mu*M)))
- ylab (expression (Cells~L^-1))
- etc.

Does anyone know how I can include the y-axis label expression in the function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `substitute` instead of `expression`. When you use `expression`, it captures the literal name inside the parentheses, whereas `substitute` will give you the actual argument that was passed to your function.

```r
x_vs_time <- function (data, xaxis, yaxis, yaxislabel) {
  
ggplot(data, aes(x = {{xaxis}}, y = {{yaxis}})) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5) + 
  ylab(substitute(yaxislabel))
}
```

Obviously, we don't have your data, but we can see this works using the built-in `iris` data set:

```r
x_vs_time(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, NO[3])
```

[image]

Or a different expression using `mtcars`

```r
x_vs_time(mtcars, wt, mpg, Si:NO[3]~drawdown)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why ` ylab (deparse(substitute(yaxislabel)))` won't work here? Thanks.

Comment: @TarJae that will turn the expression into a string, so for example `"NO[3]"` . This will be used as a character argument and printed as-is. Keeping it as an expression will allow ggplot (actually grid) to parse it as a plotmath expression.